# How to extract a field from JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Using `NewtonSoft`, I am able to parse JSON into this:

```
var jtoken = JObject.Parse(stringStuff);
Console.WriteLine(jtoken.ToString());
```

gives this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "email": "john@doe.com",
      "external-id": "af36-e9fddecdb755"
    },
    "session-token": "G_uJNNxmLNtxcmM2ilB6P_dN67p9XXk3-yn8peUBi7k3xH50Ch7MUQ+C"
  },
  "context": "/sessions"
}
```

However, if I try to get the `field` "session-token" like this,

```
var token = jtoken.Value<string>("session-token");
```

`token` is `null`. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a "session-token" property is nested inside of a "data"  property

```
string token = (string) jtoken["data"]["session-token"]; // G_uJNNxmLNtxcmM2ilB6P_dN67p9XXk3-yn8peUBi7k3xH50Ch7MUQ+C
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run through the descendants of your root object, and find the `JProperty` with the name you want -

```
 var token = root.Descendants()
                 .OfType<JProperty>()
                 .Where(x => x.Name == "session-token")
                 .FirstOrDefault()
                 ?.Value
                 ?.Value<string>();

if(token != null)
{
     //token is "G_uJNNxmLNtxcmM2ilB6P_dN67p9XXk3-yn8peUBi7k3xH50Ch7MUQ+C"
}
```

It's a little awkward, the first `.Value` returns the `JProperty`'s `JToken`, then the second `.Value` gets the string value.